# Gems in plugins often not getting loaded, when running that plugin test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

For example in open_id_authentication plugin. Inside folder test/test_helper.rb inside that plugin, it got:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'rubygems'

gem 'activesupport'
require 'active_support'

gem 'actionpack'
require 'action_controller'

gem 'mocha-0.9.8'
require 'mocha'

gem 'ruby-openid'
require 'openid'

RAILS_ROOT = File.dirname(__FILE__) unless defined? RAILS_ROOT
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../lib/open_id_authentication"
```

But whenever I run the test (both by ctrl + R in TextMate or ruby open_id_authentication.rb -v in Terminal, it returned Gem::LoadError: Could not find RubyGem mocha-0.9.8 (>= 0)

I have installed mocha gem by running both in terminal, just to made sure:

```
gem install mocha
sudo gem install mocha
```

And I even added this line in config/environment.rb

```
config.gem 'mocha'
```

so what should I do now?

Comment: And `gem 'mocha'` doesn't work too?

Comment: nope it doesn't, that was the line before I changed it, I gave up trying to run outdated plugin tests, is it really impossible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about textmate but your call should be

`ruby -Itest open_id_authentication.rb`

to include the test dir with your test helper file.

Answer (score 0):

Try and run the following command:

```
sudo bundle install moca
```

Comment: From the man page: "You should never use sudo bundle install. This is because several other steps in bundle install must be performed as the current user:

Updating your Gemfile.lock
Updating your vendor/cache, if necessary
Checking out private git repositories using your user's SSH keys"